# Quick fix for Class.forName case issue

Tags: java, class, classloader

I get this really (stupid) error from Java

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/modelclass (wrong name: models/ModelClass)
```

So I am typing in a command at the command line, and I would rather not type the proper case of the class name. I'd like to type "modelclass" instead of "ModelClass".

Is there a way to solve this? Why does this exception exist?!?

Comment: Why do you not want to type the correct case?

Comment: Why Would One Want to Type with Capitals?

Comment: One types with capitals where capitals are appropriate. onedoesnotignorepunctuationrulesjustbecauseonewantsto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error exists because the standard Java classloaders are case-sensitive to class names.

Three options:

1. Ignore standard Java conventions and name all your classes lowercase (not recommended, and not possible if you are looking for a third-party class).
2. Use [Google's Reflections Library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to look up classes in your classpath, do a case insensitive match against the given input, and use the class you find from reflection in your Class.forName() call.
3. Iteration on #2: Write your own classloader that does a case-insensitive search for classes and loads the one you want.

Comment: Don't encourage the behavior :-)

Comment: I think there's a valid use case for case-insensitive searches for class names (I like it when my IDE does it), but you're right that skipping the Java class naming conventions is not a good idea.

Comment: well, also, my question is, why are the standard Java classloaders case-sensitive to class names? There may be a good reason, and I am just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure it's intentionally case sensitive. It might be that Java is requesting a file from the OS, the OS (Windows in your case) returns a case-insensitive match, and then Java does a case-sensitive string comparison on the returned class file, notes the mismatch and throws NoClassDefFoundError.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105087/capitalization-and-noclassdeffounderror-vs-classnotfoundexception for more info.