# How to make sure a String matches a Java class name

Tags: java, string, class, reflection

Using `reflection` and the `Class.forName(String s)` method, is there a way to determine if my String matches the proper case of the class?

example:

```
Class: testReflection.java
String s: testReFlEction

try{   
    Class.forName(s)
}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Can't find class: " + s);
}
```

This misses the ClassNotFoundException and throws this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testReFlEction (wrong name: testReflection)

Error Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ReFlEction (wrong name:  testReflection)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at Reflection.findClass(testReflection.java:50)
at Reflection.main(testReflection.java:75)
```

Update:
I changed the exception to catch `Throwable`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick fix for Class.forName case issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281781/quick-fix-for-class-forname-case-issue)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that before writing the question. I will look into it and see if it solves my question.

Comment: Sidenote: the duplicate on that question is not a duplicate at all, I don't know why people closed it as such. The gist is this: you'll have to either use an external library or write your own classloader. There is no easy solution. If you however stick to naming conventions, as you should, you can solve it very easily by transforming the input into a string representing the convention.

Comment: @ Jeroen Vannevel,  He says to do a case insensitive search. I was trying to do that beforehand, which is how I came to my question. However, I can't seem to figure out how to check the actual classname with case insensitivity?

Comment: That advise goes with the google library which I assume contains a way to do this search case-insensitively. Did you use that library as well?

Comment: no, I am using straight up java, and am kinda lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the exception type I am catching from `ClassNotFoundException` to `Throwable`.